# Why does parameter translated into property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Using tsc I got

```
var Student = (function () {
    function Student(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
    return Student;
}());
```

I am wondering why parameter firstName "automatically" translated into a property of Student?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote `public` in front of the parameter names, creating a parameter property. You can remove the `public` keyword there if you don't want properties.

Comment: Could you also please add a link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties